# Gnuplot: fitting loop problems

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I need to fit some data with a gaussian function that I define with some initial parameters. I have 10 .gr files to fit and the code tells the program to do a loop for fitting them and then plot a .gif file with the evolution of the data (each file corresponds to a different time). The program works, and it ends up with the .gif and the .dat file, but it skips some .gr files. 
The code is:

```
#Define the sequence number from ARG1 to variable id
id = ARG1

#Here we generate filename from sequence number we passed to this script by command call.
filename = sprintf("FeCoBSiNbCu%04d.gr",int(id))

#Command to fit the peak with background
fit [3.68:5.45] f45(x) filename u 1:2 via x4,A4,w4,x5,A5,w5,a0,a1

#Now we write all results into formatted string:
entry1 = sprintf("%d\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t",int(id),x4,x4_err,A4,A4_err,w4,w4_err)
entry2 = sprintf("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t",x5,x5_err,A5,A5_err,w5,w5_err)

print entry1
print entry2

plot filename u 1:($0 >=0 ? $2 : 1/0) w p pt 6 ps 1 lc rgb "black" t "Experimental data",\
     filename u 1:((3.68 <= $1 && $1 <= 5.45) ? f45($1) : 1/0) w l lt 1 lw 3 lc rgb "red" t "Fitted data"
```

So I call all the files I have with 4 digits `FeCoBSiNbCu%04d.gr` but then the 0008 and the 0009 are not considered and instead it takes the 0000 in both cases.

What should I do?

Comment: How do you call your script? If you add `print id` after `id = ARG1` and `print filename` after `filename = ...`, does it print the expected output?

Comment: You don't have 8 and 9, is it possible that for some reason octal numbers, which only have letters 0 to 7, come into play?

Comment: It was the 000 that it did not like for some reason. Now it works with the numbers without the zeros